# MediaMetadataRetrieverJNI: getEmbeddedPicture failed

Tags: java, android, mediametadataretriever

Im using android and am iterating over a few hundred mediafiles to find the first embedded picture, which works well, but sends me a lot of errors in my logcat.

Im using this code:

```
for (String s : ArrayList <String> paths){
    MediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
    mmr.setDataSource(path);
    byte[] data = mmr.getEmbeddedPicture();
    if (data != null) {
    ...
}
```

the error it logs is:

```
E/MediaMetadataRetrieverJNI﹕ getEmbeddedPicture: Call to getEmbeddedPicture failed.
E/MediaMetadataRetrieverJNI﹕ getEmbeddedPicture: Call to getEmbeddedPicture failed.
E/MediaMetadataRetrieverJNI﹕ getEmbeddedPicture: Call to getEmbeddedPicture failed.
E/MediaMetadataRetrieverJNI﹕ getEmbeddedPicture: Call to getEmbeddedPicture failed.
E/MediaMetadataRetrieverJNI﹕ getEmbeddedPicture: Call to getEmbeddedPicture failed.
E/MediaMetadataRetrieverJNI﹕ getEmbeddedPicture: Call to getEmbeddedPicture failed.
.....
```

Am i using it right? If so can I suppress the error, it makes debugging annoying.
According to [MediaMetadataRetriever](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html#getEmbeddedPicture%28%29) it should simply return `null`

Comment: When you receive the error is data null, as expected?

Answer (score 0):

Using getEmbeddedPicture will not be enough You need to add a little bit code for that.

Try this

```
md.setDataSource(songsList.get(index).get("songPath"));
byte[] artBytes =  mmr.getEmbeddedPicture();
if(artBytes != null)
{
    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(mmr.getEmbeddedPicture());
    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
    imgArt.setImageBitmap(bm);
}
else
{
    imgArt.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.your_default_image));
}
```

Also look at this:

```
try {
        byte [] art = md.getEmbeddedPicture();
        Bitmap songImage = BitmapFactory
            .decodeByteArray(art, 0, art.length);
        md.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM));
        String artist =md.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST));
        String genre = md.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_GENRE));
    } catch (Exception e) {
         // TO-DO Exception
    }
```

Refer the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html)

Comment: I am using the code, but the catch block is not working.

Comment: How is this different than OP's code? He has a problem because he receives `null` and doesn't know why.

Comment: OP knows that getEmbeddedPicture returns null if the file has no embedded picture.  That is routine. OP wants to suppress the accompanying log output because it is annoying and OP has done nothing wrong.

Comment: You would think that you could pre-check for an embedded image like this:
retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_HAS_IMAGE)
but that actually doesn't work, it's not for looking for embedded images.